# IP Address filter 'before' http secured connections for protection against DDoS attacks?

Tags: tomcat, https, ddos, filtering

One technique to protect against DDoS attacks is to monitor the number or requests per seconds coming from a given IP address. Of course, IP addresses can be fakes, but let's assume this is not an issue here.

A web application installed on Tomcat (for example) can be configured to use secured http connections only (i.e., https). I am not a sysadmin expert, but I believe that in case of a DDoS attack, the high number of https connections attempts could create 100% CPU spikes.

My questions are:

1. Do DDoS attacks on https create long 100% CPU spikes?
2. Is it possible to implement a software filter to monitor
   requests-per-seconds before the SSL negotiation is started in order
   to avoid long 100% CPU spikes?
3. If answer to 2. is yes, can this be integrated in Tomcat? If
   yes how? Or it there a better solution out there?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

If answer to 2. is yes (but not in Tomcat), what solutions are available out there?

Comment: IP addresses cannot be faked in an established TCP/IP connection.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes. 3) No.

Comment: @mailq Good point about established TCP/IP. You mention yes to 2., do you have suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What platform is this?

Comment: @David Linux/Ubuntu

Comment: @JVerstry A filter in front of Tomcat. Iptables/netfilter comes into mind. SYN Coookies, too. Even application layer filters. Border Gateway Firewalls, too. Whatever is affordable.

Comment: Ubuntu's [ufw](http://sugo.ubuntu.hu/9.10/html/serverguide/hu/firewall.html) tool has a `limit` option that limits a service to 6 connections per IP address per 30 seconds. You can also use [iptables](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187).

Comment: @David Great, that's what I am looking for as a first line of defense. If any of you want to create a solution, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu's [ufw](http://sugo.ubuntu.hu/9.10/html/serverguide/hu/firewall.html) tool has a `limit` option that limits a service to 6 connections per IP address per 30 seconds. You can also use [iptables](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187).

Many of the examples are for limiting `ssh`, but just changing the port should do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to block attacks look into [ConfigServer Security & Firewall](http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html).  It manages iptables to set up rules to block attacks.  It even installs into your WHM automatically (if you're on a WHM system).

Here is where you'll find the [free version](http://configserver.com/index.html).